# Orchard CMS - Alternates

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, alternate

I've been learning to develop in Orchard recently however I'm a little stuck with an alternate I'm trying to achieve.

What I want to do is add a class when there is a widget in the Featured area and only on the homepage.

I know I can create a file named Widget-Featured.cshtml which will target all widgets in the Featured area regardless of page and I know I can create a file named Widget-url-homepage to target all widgets on the homepage.

I can't however manage to combine the two, is this possible?

Thanks for any help!
Martin

Answer (score 1):

> Widget-Featured-url-homepage.cshtml

This should do the trick. Make sure you have Url Alternates feature enabled in the backend.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but no luck I'm afraid

Comment: Are you using shape tracing to see the alternates available?

Comment: I keep getting an access denied (I think something to do with having multi-tenancy setup) when I try to install Designer Tools however when I've used shape tracing on other sites, the alternates available are either widget specific or url specific, never both.

Comment: I've just checked with the designer tool and you do get both like @Hazza says if widget and url alternatives are enabled.

Comment: Hey @Richard, what naming format does it give you? Is it as in the answer above? I've definitely got the two enabled

Comment: You need to install shape tracing from your master tenant. And then make sure you enable Widget Alternates and Url Alternates. You should see it in the list of available alternates. If the alternate you are using still doesn't work, it could be a bug. Although since it appears to be working on my machine, that seems unlikely